# Census data from file input (text)

Tags: c#, beginner, file

The program takes census data from a text file in the format age, gender, marital status, district. It then gives a list of residents by district (there are 22) and by 5 age groups. Any suggestions for improvement?

The only topics we have covered so far in class are methods, decisions, looping, and arrays.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(fStream);

        string inputRecord = "";
        string[] fields;
        int[] ageData = new int[1000];
        string[] genderData = new string[1000];
        string[] maritalData = new string[1000];
        int[] districtData = new int[1000];
        int[] countDist = new int[23];
        int[] ageGroup = new int[5];

        inputRecord = inFile.ReadLine();

        int i = 0;
        while (inputRecord != null)
        {
            fields = inputRecord.Split(',');

            ageData[i] = int.Parse(fields[0]);
            genderData[i] = fields[1];
            maritalData[i] = fields[2];
            districtData[i] = int.Parse(fields[3]);

            if (ageData[i] > 0 && ageData[i] <= 18)
            {
                ageGroup[0] = ageGroup[0] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] > 18 && ageData[i] <= 30)
            {
                ageGroup[1] = ageGroup[1] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] > 30 && ageData[i] <= 45)
            {
                ageGroup[2] = ageGroup[2] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] > 45 && ageData[i] <= 64)
            {
                ageGroup[3] = ageGroup[3] + 1;
            }
            if (ageData[i] >= 65)
            {
                ageGroup[4] = ageGroup[4] + 1;
            }

            i++;

            inputRecord = inFile.ReadLine();            
        }
        Console.WriteLine("This Program takes census data from a file and lists residents by age group and district");
        Console.WriteLine("Please ensure the file is formatted correctly! age,gender (M/F),marital status   (M/S), and district");
        for (int x = 1; x <= 22; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < districtData.Length; y++)
                if (districtData[y] == x)
                    countDist[x]++;

        for (int x = 1; x <= 22; x++)
            Console.WriteLine("District   " + x + "   has   " + countDist[x] + "   citizens");



        Console.WriteLine("------Amount of Residents per Age Group--------");
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 18 & under = {0}", ageGroup[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 18-30 = {0}", ageGroup[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 31-45 = {0}", ageGroup[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 46-64 = {0}", ageGroup[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Age Group 65 & over = {0}", ageGroup[4]);
    }
```

### EDIT

Per comments below, the instructor thinks I should get rid of the ageGroup and districtData. This is what he was suggesting I do - however, I have no idea how I'm going to change my logic that was using districtData.

```
   for (int districtCount = 1; districtCount <= 22; districtCount++)
   {
       for (int districtNumber = 0; districtNumber < districtData.Length; districtNumber++)
       {
           if (districtData[districtNumber] == districtCount)
           {
             countDist[districtCount]++;
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas:

You if conditions can be simplified.  The following to blocks are logically equivalent.  This version is yours with only `if` statements:

```
if (ageData[i] > 0 && ageData[i] <= 18)
{
    ageGroup[0] = ageGroup[0] + 1;
}
if (ageData[i] > 18 && ageData[i] <= 30)
{
    ageGroup[1] = ageGroup[1] + 1;
}
```

This version uses `if-else` statements and is equivalent as long as ageData[i] is positive:

```
if (ageData[i] > 0 && ageData[i] <= 18)
{
    ageGroup[0] = ageGroup[0] + 1;
}
else if (ageData[i] <= 30) //I removed the "ageData[i] > 18 && "
{
    ageGroup[1] = ageGroup[1] + 1;
}
```

A more advanced technique would involve storing the age ranges in a data structure so that you can edit them more easily.  You could use a dictionary that maps maximum ages to counts.

---

You should be disposing your stream objects: `fstream` and `inFile`.  Better yet, read your whole file into a string with a single line like this:

```
string[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\path\to\file.txt");
```

This uses the verbatim string literal `@`.  [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx).  Your loop will change as a result:

```
foreach(string line in contents)
{
    fields = line.Split(',');
}
```

If you haven't learned `foreach` loops yet, you can use a for loop like this:

```
for(int lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < contents.Length; lineNumber++
{
    fields = contents[lineNumber].Split(',');
    //etc.
}
```

---

You haven't said whether you've learned to use generic Lists or not.  Your arrays hold 1000 items.  If your input has more than 1000 items, you'll get an exception.  If you have learned about Lists, you should use them instead because they automatically re-size themselves when they run out of room.

Instead of:

```
int[] ageData = new int[1000];
ageData[i] = int.Parse(fields[0]);
```

You do:

```
List<int> ageData = new List<int>();
ageData.Add(int.Parse(fields[0]));  
//you have to add an int to the list before you can use it
```

---

You have numbers sprinkled around everywhere.  This is a problem for readability and maintenance.  What happens if they add a district?  I see two changes you'd have to make.  What about if the age and gender columns are reversed?  It's not so clear what changes you'd need to make to account for that.

Create constants like this:

```
const int COLUMN_AGE = 0;
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;
//etc.
```

And then do this:

```
int[] ageData = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
ageData[i] = int.Parse(fields[COLUMN_AGE]);
//etc.
```

---

Is there some reason you didn't use string formats for the following line?

```
Console.WriteLine("District   " + x + "   has   " + countDist[x] + "   citizens");
```

You can use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("District   {0}   has   {1}   citizens", x, countDist[x]);
```

---

These lines are a headache:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 22; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < districtData.Length; y++)
        if (districtData[y] == x)
            countDist[x]++;
```

You should get in the habit of using braces for all `for` loops and all but the simplest `if` statements.  Also, the variable names `x` and `y` aren't very descriptive.  Why not rename `x` to `districtCount`, and rename `y` to `districtNumber`?

```
for (int districtCount = 1; districtCount <= 22; districtCount++)
{
    for (int districtNumber = 0; districtNumber < districtData.Length; districtNumber++)
    {
        if (districtData[districtNumber] == districtCount)
        {
            countDist[districtCount]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio makes it easy to rename variables.  Right click on one and go Refactor > Rename.  Or click F2.  Don't be afraid of long variable names.  Because of Intellisense, you really only need to type them out once.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ideas. Your answer was very clear and easy for me to understand. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to help.  Don't forget to upvote answers that you like and if a submission answered your question, check it as "answered".

Answer (score 5):

user2023861 covers a lot of good ground, so I just have a couple more things to add.

First, instead of using parallel arrays, you might want to consider using a collection container like a List and filling it with objects.  Each line appears to a distinct record with a set of properties, so I would make them a simple Class:

```
public class Record
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public int District { get; set; }
}
```

That way, you don't have to hard code the size of the arrays that you are using, and you don't have to do any work to keep the related pieces of the record in synch (think what would happen if one of the arrays got sorted and the rest didn't).

Then, in your parser you can create objects for each record:

```
var records = new List<Record>();
var inputRecord = inFile.ReadLine();

while (inputRecord != null)
{
    var fields = inputRecord.Split(',');
    var currentRecord = new Record()
    {
        Age = int.Parse(fields[0]),
        Gender = fields[1],
        MaritalStatus = fields[2],
        District = int.Parse(fields[3])
    };

    records.Add(currentRecord);
    //...
}
```

You need to remember to dispose of  your FileStream and StreamReader if you are accessing them this way.  The easier and safer way to do this is with the **using** syntax, which will close and dispose of them at the ending braces.  I'd get into the habit of using this with any object with a .Dispose() method.

```
using (var fStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var inFile = new StreamReader(fStream))
    {
        //Work with the file here
        //...
    } //inFile.Dispose() happens here automatically.
} //fStream.Dispose() happens here automatically.
```

This code...

```
    for (int x = 1; x <= 22; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < districtData.Length; y++)
            if (districtData[y] == x)
                countDist[x]++;
```

...is begging for braces to make it easier to read.  It also help avoid [potential errors](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 

I talked to my instructor today about the code. He alluded to lists when I asked, "How do I know how big to make an array?" He said we won't learn about it until we take the class after this one. 

One thing he said was that I didn't need to use an array for `ageData` and `districtData`. I know I'm supposed to put my logic into the loop to avoid using two arrays. I'm not sure how to change my code to accomplish that though..

Comment: @redcell98 - You'd probably have to ask what he had in mind, because I doubt what springs to my mind is what he's after.  I'm guessing if you haven't covered Lists yet you haven't covered Linq though.  You can always do something like this using Linq: `Console.WriteLine("Age Group 18 & under = {0}", ageData.Count(x => x < 19 && x > 0));`

Comment: I updated my question with what I believe he is telling me to do.

Comment: I just rolled back the edit and added your new information below.  If you edit your code on Code Review it invalidates answers. That said, your code is basically doing what the Linq code in the above comment is doing - filling the `ageData` and `districtData` arrays as you run through the parsing loop makes more sense than getting rid of them because you don't have to iterate over the data more than once to fill them.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have not covered linq in class. So I would have no idea how to write the pseudocode, flowchart, test plan and desk check it. Keeping `ageData` and `districtData` would make my life so much easier but he said he would take off points because its not needed. I just don't know how to go about changing it.

Comment: Well, if you aren't updating counts as you go through the data read, you would need to loop through your arrays again to get the counts. Personally, I'd say that your solution makes more sense.  Analyse your code, analyse the possible alternatives, and then go to bat for your solution.  Unfortunately grading isn't always a collaborative process. A good code review process should be.  Iterating over a 1000 element array twice just to save 28 integers seems silly to me because I routinely write code that works with upward of 1,000,000 elements. You can always suggest he post *his* code here...

Comment: I'm turning it in tomorrow so I will have to see what happens. I'll be keeping `ageData` and `districtData`. The code just seems simpler if I leave it how it is. I appreciate your help with this!

Comment: The reason you don't need `districtData` is because all it's doing is holding a copy of the information you read in from the file.  The array `countDist` holds the information you need to display.  The question is: can you fill `countDist` without making a copy of the input data?  The answer is yes.  In your `while (inputRecord != null)` loop, include this line: `countDist[int.Parse(fields[3])]++;`  With this, you can remove your nested for loops that calculate `countDist`

Comment: The reason you don't need `ageData` is that for each line of input, you use the data in the age column once, and then throw it away. What do you do with the numbers in `ageData` after your `if` conditions? Nothing. Replace the `ageData` array with an `ageData` int. Set it like this: `ageData = int.Parse(fields[0]);` and read it like this `if (ageData > 0 && ageData <= 18)`. If you look at your code, with my previous comment about `districtData`, you actually don't need any of your `[1000]` sized arrays. This helps you out because you don't need to worry about files with more than 1000 rows

Comment: Got our projects back today and you were exactly right user2023861. The two arrays I was using to hold a copy of the information were unnecessary.